# Access localhost from within a docker image

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
image: python:3.8

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - cp properties_ci properties
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install net-tools

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - security
  - leanix

include:
  - ...

test:unit:
  stage: ...

test:integration:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "0"
        - python app.py &
        - curl 127.0.0.1:8126
        - py.test tests/integration/test_integration.py
    services:
        - name: cassandra:3.11
```

When I launch my python application by using the command `python app.py`  I can see the following output :

```
$ python app.py
WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Cluster.__init__ called with contact_points specified, but no load_balancing_policy. In the next major version, this will raise an error; please specify a load-balancing policy. (contact_points = ['cassandra'], lbp = None)
WARNING:cassandra.connection:An authentication challenge was not sent, this is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured authenticator = PlainTextAuthenticator)
WARNING:cassandra.connection:An authentication challenge was not sent, this is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured authenticator = PlainTextAuthenticator)
Creating keyspace if not exist...
Creating tables if not exist...
 * Serving Flask app 'src' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8126
```

So connecting to Cassandra and creating/inserting data works well, but the integration tests cannot access the python application on localhost.

In my integration tests I call http://127.0.0.1:8126 but it says the following :

```
Creating keyspace if not exist...
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/integration/test_integration.py - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8126): Max retries exceeded with url: /getCSRFToken (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f316d3df700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 3.05s ===============================
```

Any ideas how to call localhost inside the docker container so that I can access my application ? I tried also 127.0.0.1 and it does not work.

### EDIT 1

The script test_integration.py contains as a small example the following portion of code :

```
...
url = "http://localhost:8126/series/"

import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("tests/integration/20230323.zip", mode="r") as archive:
  #Iterate through files in zip file
  for zipfilename in archive.filelist:
    txtdata = archive.read(zipfilename)
    if (zipfilename.filename == 'OP_lastchange_CRUDE_2023-03-23.json'):
      payload2 = json.dumps(json.loads(txtdata))
      response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload2)
      assert response.status_code == 204, "Santa Claus is not coming this year !"
      
...
```

### EDIT 2

The solution is given by @KamilCuk - setting the python app to run in the background in the section before_script like `python app.py &` and sleeping for several seconds makes my python application available to be called like `http://localhost:8126`.

Comment: Do you want to access localhost __or__ do you want to access cassandra? I do not understand, there is nothing on localhost, if you want to connect to cassandra connect to it.

Comment: In my integration scripts I need to do POST and GET requests to the python application running in the docker container (i do call localhost:8126 for accessing my app).

Comment: You are starting the application in the background. Wait for it to start. `sleep 5` Also, instead, you should do it all in python with pytest fixtures. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks ! it makes sense these 2 extra stage : run the app in the background and sleep 5 ! I will test it and will come back to you. I need to have a look at fixtures.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you please answer the question so I can mark you answer as correct ? I am not sure about using fixtures as I want to simulate the entire behavior of the app and not mock some inputs before the tests start. Or maybe i just didn't get it right, I need to study it more.

Comment: good to hear you solved! quick tip: put the solution in a comment to this post and then check it as solution. it is way easier for people to see if it is solved

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache thanks ! I wanted KamilCuk to take the credit for this question, if he answers it I will edit it and mark it as solved. I guess he will take points for that right ?

Comment: @R13mus that's kind of you, I once did the same. but do not worry. just tag him in the answer as you already did. what matters here is to solve problems for you and who comes next! ;)

Comment: `as I want to simulate the entire behavior of the app and not mock some inputs before t` so put that in a fixture. I fail to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the working solutions, in my case, proposed by KamilCuk, is the following  :

```
image: python:3.8

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - ...
  - python app.py &
  - sleep 20 # wait for application to start-up

stages:
  - build
  - run
  - test
  - security
  - leanix

include:
  - project: ...

services:
  - name: cassandra:3.11
    alias: cassandra

test:unit:
  stage: ...

test:integration:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "0"
    - py.test tests/integration/test_series.py
```

The solution is given by @KamilCuk - setting the python app to run in the background in the section **before_script** like `python app.py &` and sleeping for several seconds `sleep 20` makes my python application available to be called like http://localhost:8126.

I need to investigate the other solution proposed by KamilCuk using fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Instead consider fixtures. Put the following in your conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(request):
   pp = subprocess.popen("python app.py")
   time.sleep(5) # TODO: replace with waiting for open port
   request.addfinalizer(lambda: (pp.terminate(), pp.wait()))
   return pp
```

Then in tests use:

```
def test_something(app):
     pass
```